# angularjs two request flow

Tags: angularjs

i am having a problem with my angularjs code. I made a code to login, but I need to verify if the current user already exists in database by email. I thought to make two requests to database. (Two $http). One to get the number of user with this email in database to validate if this is different of zero, and other to insert in database if the number of users with the email is zero, but i am having a problem. Look my code please:

[I made a service to verify the user email in database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iy7Ss.png)

this code runs, but the calls of alerts is wrong. The alert("test2") is called first then alert("test1"), but i am verifing first.

Sorry, but I am learning angular just now. This is my question! Thanks!

Comment: You need to include your code here as text, NOT an image.

Comment: hit the ```{}``` after copy pasting your code inside

Comment: Ok sorry. This is my first post here ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to move your second server request inside of your .then() handler. The current code is simply executing both server requests almost in parallel because of their async nature.

What you're looking for is something closer to this...

```
User.verificar($scope.cadastro.email).then(function(usuario){
   if(usuario.existe == true){
      //existing code
   } else {
     //make function call to insert user
   }
});
```

Comment: Very good! Thaks man. I undertood just now! I didn't know that the .then is asynchonous. Thanks for help ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's normal, the call to `.then()` is asynchronous, so in your code when you call `.then()` you make a call to your API and continue executing your code, that's why it displays "test2" first.

Try to put `alert("test2")` before `$location.path(...)`

---

You need to put the call to the second request inside the first `.then()` when the user doesn't exists

Answer (score 0):

Very well. Thaks, but I am having problems yet. I need that my function stop to run in the "return false" codes. For example:

- First: Verify if exist users with the email chose.
- Second: Add the user in the database

I saw that my code is running fist the second option. First it is saving the new user in the database, and second it is doing the verification. If the angular is asynchronous, how can I do to make two sequencial requests?

I am waiting ;)